# Why are DNS queries using CloudFlare's 1.1.1.1 server timing out?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

While attempting to use the [1.1.1.1 DNS service provided by Cloudflare](https://one.one.one.one/) on my home network, all queries timed out. I am a CenturyLink fibre (now renamed Quantum Fiber) customer. Why?

Use here means adding it as an explicit DNS resolver in a Mac, a Windows 10 PC and in a linux server running using DNSMasq as a DNS Forwarder.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

### Answer

The answer in my case is that the telco equipment commonly used in older installations by CenturyLink treats `1.1.1.1` as a "special address" that is not forwarded – it is used as a captive portal address.

To **solve the problem**: use the alternate address for the service `1.0.0.1` instead. This also applies if you also want use Cloudflare's DNS over HTTPs solution with `1.1.1.1`. This assumes that you can't update the router firmware to address this issue.

---

### Further Information

The router provided by the telco to me is a [Technicolor C2100T](https://www.centurylink.com/asset/home/help/downloads/internet/c2100t-datasheet.pdf).

This [presentation from CloudFlare](https://conference.apnic.net/46/assets/files/APNC402/DNS-resolver-1.1.1.1-from-Cloudflare.pdf) pages 14-16 identifies this model and others as exhibiting this behavior:

> - Pace (Arris) 5268
> - D-Link DMG-6661
> - Technicolor C2100T
> - Calix GigaCenter – fixed 2018/Jun/12 thanks to a USER
> - Nomadix (model(s) unknown)
> - Xerox Phaser MFP

Comment: Fun fact: If you're interested in getting your hands dirty and have a CenturyLink provided Calix C844G, you can enable Telnet/SSH on the router and manually remove the route to 1.1.1.1. The commands are similar to that on Linux. It doesn't persist over reboots, but I haven't had to reboot the thing in months.

Comment: Glad I saw this... I'm about to add a Xerox Phaser device to my network, and I would have NEVER figured out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP has answered their own question for their particular situation, I would like to point out another possible answer in the event that others may have a similar and related issue-- one which I have had.

If using Suricata, such as with pfSense, there is a rule (with similar and related consequences):

#ET POLICY Connection to previously unallocated address space 1.1.1.0/24
suppress gen_id 1, sig_id 2017000

If the rule is disabled or configured to alert only (and not drop), the problem is solved.

Comment: Curious if using 1.0.0.1 would work as well before mod ding the rule. Great detail to add to the thread!